# Placing a table foot only on even pages for a long table with supertablar

Tags: tables, supertabular

I need to typeset a very long table, where a table foot with some explanation should appear on every even page. I thought about using `supertabular`, and then defining an appropriate `\tabletail` with the help of the `ifoddpage` package. However, on all pages the table foot is marked as even. Is there a way to make this work, or possibly an alternative I could use?

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\tablefirsthead{%
  \multicolumn{4}{@{}l@{}}{\large\sffamily{unnumbered pseudo caption}}\\
  \hline
  heading a & heading s & heading d & heading f\checkoddpage \\
  \midrule
}
\tablehead{%
  \multicolumn{4}{@{}l@{}}{\large\sffamily{unnumbered pseudo caption (continued)}}\\
  \hline
  heading a & heading s & heading d & heading f\checkoddpage \\
  \midrule
}
\tabletail{\hline\ifoddpage ODD\else EVEN\fi\\}
\tablelasttail{\hline LAST}

\begin{supertabular*}{\hsize}{llll}
  A1 & S & D & F \\
  A2 & S & D & F \\
  A3 & S & D & F \\
  A4 & S & D & F \\
  A5 & S & D & F \\
  A6 & S & D & F \\
  A7 & S & D & F \\
  A8 & S & D & F \\
  A9 & S & D & F \\
  A10 & S & D & F \\
  A11 & S & D & F \\
  A12 & S & D & F \\
  A13 & S & D & F \\
  A14 & S & D & F \\
  A15 & S & D & F \\
  A16 & S & D & F \\
  A17 & S & D & F \\
  A18 & S & D & F \\
  A19 & S & D & F \\
  A20 & S & D & F \\
  A21 & S & D & F \\
  A22 & S & D & F \\
  A23 & S & D & F \\
  A24 & S & D & F \\
  A25 & S & D & F \\
  A26 & S & D & F \\
  A27 & S & D & F \\
  A28 & S & D & F \\
  A29 & S & D & F \\
  A30 & S & D & F \\
  A31 & S & D & F \\
  A32 & S & D & F \\
  A33 & S & D & F \\
  A34 & S & D & F \\
  A35 & S & D & F \\
  A36 & S & D & F \\
  A37 & S & D & F \\
  A38 & S & D & F \\
  A39 & S & D & F \\
  A40 & S & D & F \\
  A41 & S & D & F \\
  A42 & S & D & F \\
  A43 & S & D & F \\
  A44 & S & D & F \\
  A45 & S & D & F \\
  A46 & S & D & F \\
  A47 & S & D & F \\
  A48 & S & D & F \\
  A49 & S & D & F \\
  A50 & S & D & F \\
  A51 & S & D & F \\
  A52 & S & D & F \\
  A53 & S & D & F \\
  A54 & S & D & F \\
  A55 & S & D & F \\
  A56 & S & D & F \\
  A57 & S & D & F \\
  A58 & S & D & F \\
  A59 & S & D & F \\
  A60 & S & D & F \\
  A61 & S & D & F \\
  A62 & S & D & F \\
  A63 & S & D & F \\
  A64 & S & D & F \\
  A65 & S & D & F \\
  A66 & S & D & F \\
  A67 & S & D & F \\
  A68 & S & D & F \\
  A69 & S & D & F \\
  A70 & S & D & F \\
  A71 & S & D & F \\
  A72 & S & D & F \\
  A73 & S & D & F \\
  A74 & S & D & F \\
  A75 & S & D & F \\
  A76 & S & D & F \\
  A77 & S & D & F \\
  A78 & S & D & F \\
  A79 & S & D & F \\
  A80 & S & D & F \\
  A81 & S & D & F \\
  A82 & S & D & F \\
  A83 & S & D & F \\
  A84 & S & D & F \\
  A85 & S & D & F \\
  A86 & S & D & F \\
  A87 & S & D & F \\
  A88 & S & D & F \\
  A89 & S & D & F \\
  A90 & S & D & F \\
  A91 & S & D & F \\
  A92 & S & D & F \\
  A93 & S & D & F \\
  A94 & S & D & F \\
  A95 & S & D & F \\
  A96 & S & D & F \\
  A97 & S & D & F \\
  A98 & S & D & F \\
  A99 & S & D & F \\
  A100 & S & D & F \\
\end{supertabular*}

\end{document}
```

### aux file

```
\relax 
\providecommand \oddpage@label [2]{}
\oddpage@label{2}{1}
\oddpage@label{3}{2}
\oddpage@label{4}{3}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the commands `\checkoddpage` in the `tablefirstheader` and `tablehead` settings. Put this command right before the `\ifoddpage` command in the tabletail setting.

To avoid the warning of underfull hbox. I add the command `@{\extracolsep{\fill}\hspace{\tabcolsep}}` before the first the column specifier. In this way, every columns are automatically spaced evenly according to the `\hsize`.

Here is the working code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\tablefirsthead{%
  \multicolumn{4}{@{}l@{}}{\large\sffamily{unnumbered pseudo caption}}\\
  \hline
  heading a & heading s & heading d & heading f \\
  \midrule
}
\tablehead{%
  \multicolumn{4}{@{}l@{}}{\large\sffamily{unnumbered pseudo caption (continued)}}\\
  \hline
  heading a & heading s & heading d & heading f \\
  \midrule
}
\tabletail{\hline\checkoddpage\ifoddpage ODD\else EVEN\fi\\}
\tablelasttail{\hline LAST\\ }

\begin{supertabular*}{\hsize}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}\hspace{\tabcolsep}}llll}
  A1 & S & D & F \\
  A2 & S & D & F \\
  A3 & S & D & F \\
  A4 & S & D & F \\
  A5 & S & D & F \\
  A6 & S & D & F \\
  A7 & S & D & F \\
  A8 & S & D & F \\
  A9 & S & D & F \\
  A10 & S & D & F \\
  A11 & S & D & F \\
  A12 & S & D & F \\
  A13 & S & D & F \\
  A14 & S & D & F \\
  A15 & S & D & F \\
  A16 & S & D & F \\
  A17 & S & D & F \\
  A18 & S & D & F \\
  A19 & S & D & F \\
  A20 & S & D & F \\
  A21 & S & D & F \\
  A22 & S & D & F \\
  A23 & S & D & F \\
  A24 & S & D & F \\
  A25 & S & D & F \\
  A26 & S & D & F \\
  A27 & S & D & F \\
  A28 & S & D & F \\
  A29 & S & D & F \\
  A30 & S & D & F \\
  A31 & S & D & F \\
  A32 & S & D & F \\
  A33 & S & D & F \\
  A34 & S & D & F \\
  A35 & S & D & F \\
  A36 & S & D & F \\
  A37 & S & D & F \\
  A38 & S & D & F \\
  A39 & S & D & F \\
  A40 & S & D & F \\
  A41 & S & D & F \\
  A42 & S & D & F \\
  A43 & S & D & F \\
  A44 & S & D & F \\
  A45 & S & D & F \\
  A46 & S & D & F \\
  A47 & S & D & F \\
  A48 & S & D & F \\
  A49 & S & D & F \\
  A50 & S & D & F \\
  A51 & S & D & F \\
  A52 & S & D & F \\
  A53 & S & D & F \\
  A54 & S & D & F \\
  A55 & S & D & F \\
  A56 & S & D & F \\
  A57 & S & D & F \\
  A58 & S & D & F \\
  A59 & S & D & F \\
  A60 & S & D & F \\
  A61 & S & D & F \\
  A62 & S & D & F \\
  A63 & S & D & F \\
  A64 & S & D & F \\
  A65 & S & D & F \\
  A66 & S & D & F \\
  A67 & S & D & F \\
  A68 & S & D & F \\
  A69 & S & D & F \\
  A70 & S & D & F \\
  A71 & S & D & F \\
  A72 & S & D & F \\
  A73 & S & D & F \\
  A74 & S & D & F \\
  A75 & S & D & F \\
  A76 & S & D & F \\
  A77 & S & D & F \\
  A78 & S & D & F \\
  A79 & S & D & F \\
  A80 & S & D & F \\
  A81 & S & D & F \\
  A82 & S & D & F \\
  A83 & S & D & F \\
  A84 & S & D & F \\
  A85 & S & D & F \\
  A86 & S & D & F \\
  A87 & S & D & F \\
  A88 & S & D & F \\
  A89 & S & D & F \\
  A90 & S & D & F \\
  A91 & S & D & F \\
  A92 & S & D & F \\
  A93 & S & D & F \\
  A94 & S & D & F \\
  A95 & S & D & F \\
  A96 & S & D & F \\
  A97 & S & D & F \\
  A98 & S & D & F \\
  A99 & S & D & F \\
  A100 & S & D & F \\
\end{supertabular*}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Works like a charm! I thought I had tested putting the `\checkoddpage` in the table tail, but apparently I did something wrong. Thanks a lot!